# Abstract classes and class organization in C++

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I would like to create a basic abstract class in C++, where the subclasses are each in a separate file. My abstract class looks something like

```
class Process_Base{
    public:
        virtual void process() = 0;
}
```

Should a simple implementation like this be contained entirely in a header file? If it is do I need to have a .cpp file associated with it?

When I create the subclasses what should their header file look? I was thinking .cpp file for the subclass should look something like

```
#include "Process_Base.h"

class Hello_Process : public Process_Base{
    void process(){
        printf("%s\n", "Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Could someone verify that I am approaching this correctly, and if not give a simple example of what I should be doing.

**UPDATE**

I continued with the implementation but I am now getting the following compiler error

```
g++ -c -Wall -g Process_Message.cpp
Process_Message.cpp:4: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

The following is the abstract class header

```
// Abstract header .hpp file
class Process_Base{
    public:
        virtual void process() = 0;
};
```

the subclass header

```
// The subclass header .hpp file
#include "Process_Base.hpp"

class Process_Message : public Process_Base {
public:
    void process();
};
```

and the implementation

```
// Simple implementation .cpp file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class Process_Message : Process_Base {

public: 
    void process(){
        printf("%s", "Hello");
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error, can someone please explain.

Comment: The sub classes should declare any additional methods etc in their respective header files. No cpp file needed for the base class if it is abstract. Looks good so far!

Comment: Most likely your base class requires a virtual destructor.

Comment: You should place a semicolon after the classes' closing brackets. Just like that: class A{};

Answer (score 0):

You're missing ; at the end of Process_Base declaration, when you include the file, the compiler goes nut. correct is:

```
class Process_Base{
    public:
         virtual void process() = 0;
};
```

Comment: I copied the class in wrong, the ';' is there in the file, I have corrected the posting

Comment: then double check your include, also try to move the base class declaration inside the derived class header, to check that the problem is with the inclusion, as the error says, Process_Base is unknown to the compiler...

Answer (score 0):

Why this 'Process_Base' is there in below code? You have already mentioned inheritance in header file,right?

```
// Simple implementation .cpp file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class Process_Message : Process_Base {

public: 
    void process(){
        printf("%s", "Hello");
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to type ';' at the end of the class declaration after '}'

Answer (score 0):

Your correct code should look like this:

//Process_Message.h

```
#include "Process_Base.hpp"

class Process_Message : public Process_Base {
public:
    void process();
};
```

//Process_Message.cpp

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include "Process_Message.h"

      void Process_Message::process()
      {
           printf("%s", "Hello");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to declare your overrides as `virtual`, or they will hide parent methods instead of implementing them.

```
#include <iostream>

class Process_Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Process_Base() {}
    virtual void process() =0;
};

class Process_Message : public Process_Base
{
public:
    virtual void process(); // <- virtual
};

void Process_Message::process()
{
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

The above should compile fine